# Animate a fixed element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I get an issue when I try to animate a fixed element on my dom using jQuery.

```
    var increased = false;

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){

        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if( scrollTop >= 118 && !increased ){
            $('header nav').animate({
                height: '116px'
            }, 500, 'linear', function(){
                increased = true;
            });
        }

        if( scrollTop < 118 && increased ){
            $('header nav').animate({
                height: '50px'
            }, 500, 'linear', function(){
                increased = false;
            });
        }

    });
```

My nav : http://glui.me/?i=g6to3wnugmtt1je/2014-02-06_at_20.28_2x_(1).png/

After animate : http://glui.me/?i=vtfadya588b5mx7/2014-02-06_at_20.30_2x.png/

Comment: You're sure `$(document).scroll....` returns something? I would think `window` would be more appropriate, as in `$(window).on('scroll')`

Comment: No it works but look at my menu, this one is hidden with the animate function...